# Excluding unordered list items count from an ordered list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to style the numbers next to my unordered list within my ordered list.

For some reason, however, Item A1, Item A2 & Item B1 seem to be including themselves with the counter.

What needs to be done so that ONLY the title for List A and B have that counter?

[image]

```css
.ordered {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 3em;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: li-counter;
}
.ordered li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  min-height: 3em;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
}
.ordered li::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -01em;
  width: 0.8em;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  color: #fff;
  content: counter(li-counter);
  counter-increment: li-counter;
}
/*unordered list*/
.unordered ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
.unordered li {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}
* { background-color: black; }
```

```html
<ol class="ordered">
  <li>List A
    <br>
    <ul class="unordered">
      <li>Item A1</li>
      <li>Item A2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>List B
    <br>
    <ul class="unordered">
      <li>Item B1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
.ordered li::before { ... }
```

Do this:

```
.ordered > li::before { ... }
```

In your code, you're targeting all `li` elements with a *descendant combinator* (the space between selectors). Per its name, it targets all descendants.

Instead, use a child combinator (`>`), which targets only the children.